# onchange event not working at begining of page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I have a web application which has an onchange event for loading multiple select options to a textbox separated by ',' and slice the last ','
It's working fine,
I have an another function for form filling. When I try to load the form only select option is being updated expecting onchange function to get data from select and have some value in textbox.
But sadly it's not working but working only after new option is selected or removed and added back

Function for adding multiple select data to textbox with onchange event:

```
// arguments: reference to select list, callback function (optional)
function getSelectedOptions(sel,fn) {
    var opts = [], opt;
    // loop through options in select list
    for (var i=0, len=sel.options.length; i<len; i++) {
        opt = sel.options[i];
        // check if selected
        if ( opt.selected ) {
            // add to array of option elements to return from this function
            opts.push(opt);
            // invoke optional callback function if provided
            if (fn) {
              fn(opt);
            }}}
    // return array containing references to selected option elements
    return opts;
}

// example callback function (selected options passed one by one)
function callback(opt) {
    // display in textarea for this example
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
    display.innerHTML += opt.value + ',';
}

// anonymous function onchange for select list with id lstBox2
document.getElementById('sel1').onchange = function(e) {
    // get reference to display textareaa
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
    display.innerHTML = ''; // reset
    // callback fn handles selected options
    getSelectedOptions(this, callback);
    // remove ', ' at end of string
    var str = display.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
    display.innerHTML = str;
};
```

Function to form filling:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
               tests = split[testIndex];
              // $('#display2').val(tests);
               var opt2 = '<option selected>' + tests + '</option>';
               $('#sel').append(opt2);})
```

Comment: Onchange works when you change the element you bind it to. You should do the same for onload

Comment: I tried same with onload but it did not work,
Same tried keeping it in document.ready but still problem lies

Comment: Onload iOS the same of document.ready. Plain js vs jquery

Comment: I tried having it in ready and onload it did not work!!!

Comment: so, can you provide a [mcve] (snippet) where we can reproduce the problem and try to help better?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your document.getElementById('sel1').onchange code into the $(document).ready(...) block.  It's hard to tell without a complete page example, but one possibility is that 'sel1' isn't part of the DOM yet when you try to add the onchange handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$('body').on('change', '#sel1', function(e) {

});
```

instead if the elements are added after load.

Comment: I added it but there no difference but same as before.